# How to get all the values after : in the json

Tags: javascript, split, substring, pattern-matching, multiple-matches

I want to extract all the input values which is available in the JSON using JavaScript.

I want to extract the value which is coming after `"InputFieldTitle1 :"`. I tried with substring but it is giving only InputFieldTitle1 value and not InputFieldTitle2.

```
"payload": "{input : {  
  InputFieldTitle1 : “Input1”, 
  InputFieldTitle2 : “Input2”, 
  },}"
```

Comment: What is the source of this data?  The value for `payload` is *almost* valid JSON to simply be deserialized, but those stylized quotes (and the lack of property name quotes) break that.  Is there any way to correct the source of the data to return valid JSON?

Comment: If it was a valid json then `JSON.parse(data).payload.input.InputFieldTitle1 `